# After Js minification site taking wrong js path in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2

I have recently updated my Magento 2.3.4 to Magento 2.4.2 . After upgrade I tried to set production mode but js minification not working. It takes wrong js path.
I am using the nginx web server. I tried all magento default commands and cleared the static files also.

Anyone could you please help me to fix the issue?